# Nested collection view partial in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass a `Kids` collection from my main view to a partial. This main view is strongly typed and the `Kids` attribute is a `has_many` association for the `MainModel`.

I have my default details view where my `@model MyApp.Models.MainModel`.

Inside this view, I want to show its children,

`@Html.Partial("_KidsView", Model.Kids)`

which is configured like this in my `MainModel.cs`:

`public ICollection<Kid> Kids { get; set; }`

and is specified in my parital `_KidsView` as such:

`@model ICollection<MyApp.Models.Kid>`

I am getting an `InvalidOperationException` where it says

```
The model passed into this the dictionary if of type
'System.Data.Entity.DyanmicProxies.MainModel_#WHOLE_BUNCH_OF_NUMBERS'
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'System.Collections.Genereic.ICollection[MyApp.Models.Kid]
```

I have tried not using a partial and calling the `foreach` loop directly on `@foreach (var item in Model.Kids)` but that hasn't worked either.

How can I properley pass this in?

I feel like I may be doing something obviously wrong but I can't see it.

EDIT:

Ok, so the solution isn't working. I figure it's something in one of my models that's not right.

Here is Kid.cs:

```
[Column("main_model_id")]
public int MainModelID { get; set; }
public virtual MainModel MainModel {get; set; }
```

and MainModel.cs

`public ICollection<Kid> Kids { get; set; }`

Comment: have you tried using a list instead of an ICollection?

Comment: Change model ICollection<MyApp.Models.Kid> to model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Kid>

Comment: Can you show what you do with model inside _KidsView ?

Comment: The problem here is you're only showing us some of the code.  You need to show us your complete Kid definition, and your complete MainModel definition.  Also your complete partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is explicit and can really only be caused by two things:

1. Your model specification in your partial view is incorrect, which you say it's not.
2. You're passing in the wrong thing to the call to `Partial` or `RenderPartial`. Specifically, if you do not specify the model argument, it's filled with the main view's model by default (which seems to be happening based on the error, but the call you have in your question is correct).

Since it seems neither of those is the case, I can only assume there's some kind of caching going on or some other "stickiness" that causing your current code to not actually be the code that's running. Stop and restart debugging, and maybe even close Visual Studio and try again, after the confirm that your code is indeed correct.

An alternative solution is to use a display template instead - it's pretty much like a partial view, but a little cleaner in situations like this.

1. In your "Views" folder, create a new folder called "DisplayTemplates". In that folder, create a partial view called "Kid.cshtml". Strongly-type that view to your `Kid` model (not an enumerable, just `Kid`). Add the HTML that should be rendered for one instance of a `Kid`.
2. In your main view add the following:

   ```
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Kids)
   ```
3. Party!

Comment: I tried using a Display Template. The page displayed without error but the children were not visible. I updated my post with details of the implementation just in case you see something there. I went to the Kids index and on that end, the `MainModel` attributes were visible (as in `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MainModel.Name)` so I'm kinda confused.

Comment: You're missing the `virtual` on your `ICollection<Kid>` property. Without the `virtual`, Entity Framework can't override the property in the proxy descendant it creates and, thus, can't actually fill the collection with `Kid`s from the database.

Comment: :)...So I was missing something pretty obvious. At least I learned a new tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should do it; let's say this is your main Model:

```
public class MainModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Kid> Kids { get; set; }
  // Other properties
}
```

Do this in your main View:

```
@model MyApp.Models.MainModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kids)
```

Then, create a partial view like below, name it Kid.cshtml, and place it under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates:

```
@model MyApps.Models.Kid

@* Your html helpers (input fields) *@
```